# How to behave with long strings in Flutter/Dart to make code clean?

Tags: flutter, dart

I wonder how to behave with long strings to make code clean.
Code example:

```
Text(
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.',
)
```

Is it good approach to have such a string in one line of code?
It is contrary to [lines_longer_than_80_chars](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/lines_longer_than_80_chars.html) lint.
Or it is better to split it into mulitple lines like:

```
Text(
  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing '
  'elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et '
  'dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis '
  'nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut '
  'aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure '
  'reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore '
  'eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat '
  'cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia '
  'deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.',
)
```

Such a splitting is time-consuming, is there any way to make it automatically, with formatter for example?

Maybe there is any better approach?

Answer (score 1):

If your string is *that* large, have you considered using [assets](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images#loading-text-assets)?

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - lipsum.txt
```

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

Future<String> loadAsset() async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/lipsum.txt');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's time-consuming solution, nevertheless for **large** strings great approach to keep code clean.